# jQuery check flash requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, iframe

I have the following scenario,

I'm loading an iframe in a page where I have full control over,

The inside of the iframe is a webpage that embeds a flash file. I have no control over the inside of the iframe (that includes the actual flash and the webpage that embeds the flash).

I want to know if there was a GET request to download a certain image. The GET request is originated by the flash file.

Note: I can see the images that the flash loads if I click CTRL+SHIFT+I on Chrome under resources if that helps you understand how the flash movie gets the images.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Directly no; you can't to this regardless of whether you own the iframe and the SWF or not. So the answer is a no, not unless you own the images being requested and you can implement some sort of server-side static resources tracker.

Or you can always decompile the swf file (which is highly discouraged).